# Any way to reduce the file size? (cefsharp winforms c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium, cefsharp

I have a form with a chromium browser. The build size is around 120 megabytes.
Is there anyway to reduce this?

(When I uninstall the cef package and use a regular webcontrol, my app folder is 5 megabyte.)

Comment: How big is your Chrome folder?

Comment: Considering it's an entire browser, I'd say 120MB is pretty good going. As @amaitland hints, a `Google Chrome` installation is (for me, with extensions) 321MB

Comment: i think we're in a same situation here.... wondering how to compress them all at once...

Answer (score 1):

No. But a way to decrease the size of future updates is to use for example [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/develop/docs/using/delta-packages.md)
which can send just the bytes that differ, not the whole 120 MB each time.